# How to compress an image to PNG format without directly writing it to a .png file

Tags: lwjgl

Using the LWJGL - STB library i can use:

```
STBImageWrite.stbi_write_png
```

to compress and write raw rgba values directly to a .png file.

Is there a way to compress the same rgba values to a java.nio.Buffer instead?

I can only guess that what i need is:

```
public static boolean stbi_write_png_to_func(@NotNull org.lwjgl.stb.STBIWriteCallbackI func,
                                             long context,
                                             int w,
                                             int h,
                                             int comp,
                                             @NotNull java.nio.ByteBuffer data,
                                             int stride_in_bytes)
```

where the STBIWriteCallbackI must implement:

```
void (*invoke) (
       void *context,
       void *data,
       int size
   )
```

But the [documentation](https://www.cs.unh.edu/%7Ecs770/lwjgl-javadoc/lwjgl-stb/org/lwjgl/stb/STBImageWrite.html#stbi_write_png_to_func-org.lwjgl.stb.STBIWriteCallbackI-long-int-int-int-java.nio.ByteBuffer-int-) is not very clear. And I can't find any usage examples.

**Can someone explain or provide an example on how to use this function?**
(Is *data a pointer to the compressed image?)

Comment: The documentation is quite clear about its arguments. What exactly don't you understand? `Is *data a pointer to the compressed image?` Yes. To part of it at least. It'll be called multiple times potentially.

Comment: @tkausl correction: It's not clear to me :). So the callback get's invoked for each "pixel"?

Comment: No, It'll be called for some amount of encoded data once the internal buffer fills up, such that the library does not dynamically allocate/reallocate buffers.

Comment: @tkausl I am not used to working with native code. I was thinking that the *data is a pointer to the start of the image, and the size is the total size of the compressed image in bytes. And that you might need to get that data using the *data pointer in another function. Something like that.

Comment: @tkausl Could you perhaps provide an example? It would be very helpful

Comment: Just pass the other arguments as usual and a func which does nothing but print out the size, to see whats "coming in". Thats your png data. `Could you perhaps provide an example?` Unfortunately I can't right now.

Comment: @tkausl I will try and see what get's printed.  "Thats your png data". What is? The actual bytes of the "long data" ?

Comment: `The actual bytes of the "long data" ?` Yes. Well, its a pointer, so you have to read the memory somehow. To be honest, thats the worst possible way one could implement this java to c interface...

Comment: Well it only prints one time:  "context: 2396356000960 data: 2396502827968 size: 1534" And the 1534 corresponds exactly to the size of the compressed .png. So i would guess the *data is a pointer to the memory location. It would be weird if lwjgl didn't have a dedicated method to get the data as a .nio.Buffer

Comment: @tkausl Also you have to free the callback apparently as it leaks memory.

Comment: @tkausl There actually was a dedicated function for this. The  STBIWriteCallback itself has a static method "getData(long data, int size)" and can only be used within the invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can. To compress an image without writing it directly to a .png file:

**EDIT.** (The compressed image memory is temporarily allocated for usage within the invoke call of the callback. In the example below i am using the ByteBuffer outside of the invocation. You can't do that.)

```
private final static class CompressCallback extends STBIWriteCallback implements Disposable {
    
        public ByteBuffer compressed_img;
        public int compressed_size;
        
        public void invoke(long context, long data, int size) {
            compressed_img = STBIWriteCallback.getData(data, size);
            compressed_size = size;
        }
        public void dispose() {
            Callback.free(address());
        }
}
```

```
CompressCallback callback = new CompressCallback();
STBImageWrite.stbi_write_png_to_func(
callback,
window_handle,
image_width,
image_height,
image_components,
image_data,
image_width * image_channels);

callback.dispose();
MemoryUtils.memfree(image_data);
ByteBuffer compressed_image = callback.compressed_img;
int compressed_bytes = callback.compressed_size;
```